# How to fix "com.android.Volley.TimeoutError" in android while trying to perform a registration activity

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-networking

I am using wamp server as my localhost and I have an app that I want to capture user's particulars during registration. Notwithstanding, the app runs fine on my mobile phone but when I fill the the editText and click my registration button I get this error "Registration Errorcom.android.Volley.TimeoutError".

I have tried checking for any errors in the logcat but found none. Anyone who is good at Android (Java) programing could kindly help me resolve this. Here is my layout code and the java class code. Thanks in advance

```
My Layout Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:paddingTop="60dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark2"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_white" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/constituency"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/county"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/C2olorText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
enter code here
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_regist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/register"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

```
The Java class code

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText name, constituency, email, password, c_password;
private Button btn_regist;
private ProgressBar loading;
private static String URL_REGIST = "http://192.168.0.115/kpp/register.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    constituency = findViewById(R.id.constituency);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    c_password = findViewById(R.id.c_password);
    btn_regist = findViewById(R.id.btn_regist);

    btn_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Regist();
        }
    });

}
private void Regist(){
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_regist.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final String name = this.name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String constituency =     this.constituency.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

            if(success.equals("1")){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws    AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name",name);
            params.put("constituency",constituency);
            params.put("email",email);
            params.put("password",password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}`enter code here`
```

}

I expect upon successful registration it toast to notify the user "Registration Successful!"...

Answer (score 2):

In your request set Retry policy:

```
public static int TIMEOUT_MS=10000        //10 seconds

     myRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                TIMEOUT_MS, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Here with variable `TIMEOUT_MS` you can specify timeout in milliseconds.

Comment: After specified time period exception will be thrown.

Comment: kindly edit my code if you wont  for me to get the concept please?

Answer (score 1):

use retry policy like this

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));

requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Rather than repeatedly add the same answer to multiple questions, the correct response is usually to identify which question has the most useful answers and use the flag button under the other questions and flag them as duplicates of the other. Multiple identical answers get auto-flagged to moderators who will usually delete them.

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried to link all the question with same ans but didn't know how to do that. That is why i put same ans for every question.